# Don't know what happened but since last week my Laptop started flashing Dell logo three times before OS actually start booting

Tags: boot, grub2, dell, 19.10

Sometimes it happens like this: **Dell Logo** > **Ubuntu purple screen** > **Dell logo** > **Ubuntu purple screen** > **Dell logo** > **finally booting with Ubuntu purple screen.**

I use the ZFS file system in Ubuntu 19.10. If there is any output that is required, I will be happy to link it here.